# Database Table Name Suggestions

Tags: sql-server, database, naming

I'm working on a table which will contain data regarding a deputy registrar that was responsible for recruiting a person to register to vote.

Here's are the fields the table will have:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
 Id | VoterRegistrationId  | DeputyRegistrarId
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm kind of stuck on coming up with a name for this table so I figured I'd get some help.

I was thinking DeputyRegistrarVoterRegistration, but that named seemed a bit too wordy.

Comment: Might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631850/how-do-you-name-your-many-to-many-relationship-tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have tables named Voter and DeputyRegistrar?

If so, I'd just recommend VoterDeputyRegistrar, or DeputyRegistrarVoter as this table merely glues rows from the other two tables together.

**Edit:** In response to the comment, I would recommend you go with your original approach (DeputyRegistrarVoterRegistration). Abbreviations are a tricky thing sometimes, and once you start, you have to remember how you abbreviated. They also add (however slightly) to your cognitive load when you are working with the abbreviated names. Not to mention, in this case - if you did abbreviate, you'd still have two other tables that make up the name that weren't abbreviated.

For future reference, and as a nod to readability and brevity - maybe you should have named your table Registrar rather than DeputyRegistrar - only if there is no other type of Registrar of course. When you are querying from and joining on these tables, just use a short alias and you still have very readable code.

Comment: I have tables named Voter, VoterRegistration, & DeputyRegistrar

Answer (score 0):

A lot of database designs I've seen tend to have things like VOTER_TO_DEPUTY